# Adding a shapefile to raster

Tags: r, raster, shapefile

**EDIT**

```
x <- raster::getData('worldclim', var='tmin', res = 10)
s <- stack(x$tmin1,x$tmin12)
sp <- as(s, 'SpatialGridDataFrame')

fra <- raster::getData('GADM',country = 'FRA', level = 2)
my.layer <- list("sp.polygons", fra, col = "black")    
spplot(sp, names.attr = c("tmin1","tmin12"), sp.layout = my.layer)
```

[image]

How do I plot `fra` on top of the raster and not underneath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
library(latticeExtra)
spplot(s, names.attr = c("tmin1","tmin12")) + layer(sp.polygons(fra, lwd = 2))
```

Note that I use RasterStack `s`, there is no need to create a SpatialGridDataFrame.

You can also do

```
p <- spplot(s, names.attr = c("tmin1","tmin12")) 
p + layer(sp.polygons(fra, lwd = 2))
```

If you have ggplot2 loaded, this will trigger an error: `Error: Attempted to create layer with no geom.`

To avoid that, use the latticeExtra namespace prefix.

```
 p + latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(fra, lwd = 2))
```

Comment: hmm.. not sure why but  I get this error `Error: Attempted to create layer with no geom`